# Iframe pin name not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps, iframe, google-maps-markers

I have longitude and latitude.I just need to have pin name Marigold in the  following figure.Any help will be great.

[image]

I tried iframe:

```
  <iframe class="map-area" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=31.833981,75.116343+&hl=es;z=14&amp;output=embed">Marigold Public School</iframe><br />
```